# nested map in cassandra data modelling

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have following requirement of my dataset, need to unserstand what datatype should I use and how to save my data accordingly :-

```
CREATE TABLE events (
id text,
evntoverlap map<text, map<timestamp,int>>,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

evntoverlap = {
               'Dig1': {{'2017-10-09 04:10:05', 0}}, 
               'Dig2': {{'2017-10-09 04:11:05', 0},{'2017-10-09 04:15:05', 0}},
               'Dig3': {{'2017-10-09 04:11:05', 0},{'2017-10-09 04:15:05', 0},{'2017-10-09 04:11:05', 0}}
              }
```

This gives an error :-

```
Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Non-frozen collections are not allowed inside collections: map<text, map<timestamp, int>>"
```

How should I store this type of data in single column . Please suggest datatype and insert command for the same. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is limitation of Cassandra - you can't nest collection (or UDT) inside collection without making it frozen.  So you need to "froze" one of the collections - either nested:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
id text,
evntoverlap map<text, frozen<map<timestamp,int>>>,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

or top-level:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
id text,
evntoverlap frozen<map<text, map<timestamp,int>>>,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html#reference_ds_exb_vg5_yj__using-frozen-in-collection) for more details.

Comment: Ok so I created column as evntoverlap frozen<map<text, map<timestamp,int>>> Now, I inserted record - insert into events (id , evntoverlap ) values('1',{'dig1':{'2019-10-09 09:08:07':1}}); Now trying to add more record in same key by this - UPDATE events set evntoverlap = evntoverlap + {'dig1':{'2019-10-10 09:10:07':1}} where id = '1'  It gives error as - InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid operation (evntoverlap = evntoverlap + {'dig1': {'2019-10-10 09:10:07': 1}}) for frozen collection column evntoverlap"

Comment: This is existing limitation of Cassandra - you can't nest collection (or UDT) inside collection without making it frozen.

Comment: So you mean to say I should create nest map also as frozen  in order to set multiple values in nested map ?

Comment: You need to set nested map frozen, and then update it completely (read existing value & add your new data). Can you describe the task that you want to solve?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I was on vacations , Your advice helped me to go ahead. I have accepted your answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

CQL collections limited to 64kb, if putting things like maps in maps you might push that limit. Especially with frozen maps you are deserializing the entire map, modifying it, and re inserting. Might be better off with a

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id text,
  evnt_key, text
  value map<timestamp, int>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id), evnt_key)
  )
```

Or even a

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id text,
  evnt_key, text
  evnt_time timestamp
  value int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id), evnt_key, evnt_time)
  )
```

It would be more efficient and safer while giving additional benefits like being able to order the event_time's in ascending or descending order.